# DB2 Dynamic query execution which returns row count

Tags: db2, prepared-statement, dynamicquery, execute-immediate

Here i am trying to run a dynamic query in DB2 which returns row count in a variable.

Could anyone help me out how to store the result of a dynamic  query into a variable so that I could use it further? Below are code snippet:--

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_REC_COUNT ( )
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  EXTERNAL ACTION
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
BEGIN
DECLARE SQL_STR VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE V_TabSchema VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE V_TabName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE CNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CountCur CURSOR FOR select TabSchema,TabName from SysCat.Tables where TabSchema='NGCORE' or TabSchema='NGCOREAU';
    OPEN CountCur;
        CountCur_Loop1:LOOP
        FETCH CountCur INTO  V_TabSchema,V_TabName;
        IF SQLCODE = 0
        THEN
          SET  SQL_STR ='select count(*) into CNT  from '|| V_TabSchema||'.'||V_TabName;
            PREPARE SQ FROM SQL_STR;
            execute  SQ;
            SET  SQL_STR ='INSERT INTO NGCORE_TMP.PHYISICAL_BACKOUT_REC_CNT(SCHEMA_NM,TABLE_NM,BEFORE_CNT)VALUES('''||V_TabSchema||''','''||V_TabName||''','||CNT||')';         
            PREPARE SQL FROM SQL_STR;
            EXECUTE SQL;
        ELSE
            CLOSE CountCur;
            LEAVE CountCur_Loop1;
        END If;
        END LOOP CountCur_Loop1;

END;
```

Getting below error:- 
ERROR [42703] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0206N  "CNT" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first issue [PREPARE with an OUTPUT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000954.htm) clause, and then the [EXECUTE with an INTO](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000954.htm) statement.

I can't seem to find an example in the IBM docs.

Comment: Excellent @Pravin - please edit my answer or add your own with the solution for future reference - thanks.